# NiFi-1.1.1 template import error

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to import a template in NiFi-1.1.1 and I get this message:

`The specified observer identifier already exists.`

and it only imports a part of the template.

This NiFi instance is running in cluster mode. If I try to put the same template on a local nifi instance, either 1.0 or 1.1, it works.
I've tried to remove the controller service and try to import without a controller service,  but I still get this error.

Any ides how can I avoid it ?

Comment: What version was the template made with? There was an existing bug that has been addressed in Apache NiFi 1.1.1. However, the issue was with template generation. So if your template was generated with an earlier version, you may still see this message.

Comment: the version of nifi was 1.0 and I am trying to import that template in nifi-1.1.1

Comment: On my laptop, I have a nifi-1.1.1 and I can import that template. When I am trying to import that template on a nifi that is running in cluster mode, in a cluster ... I have this issue.

Comment: Are you able to recreate the template from nifi-1.1.1 on your laptop and attempt to import that into your cluster? If the template you're attempting to import into your cluster was generated with 1.0 you're going to see that message.

Comment: It happens the same

Comment: Would it be possible to share that template with the Apache NiFi team on one of their mailing lists? There's a chance that your hitting a new/different issue based on your flow configuration.

https://nifi.apache.org/mailing_lists.html